# How do you detect if an Android device has a camera?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I want to disable camera functionality in my app, if the device does not have a camera. However, I seem to have stumbled into a bug when doing so.

According to the official Android Developer docs, I can use `hasSystemFeature()` to detect device features at runtime, as shown below:

```java
boolean hasAnyCamera = this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY);
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "hasAnyCamera = " + hasAnyCamera);

boolean hasBackCamera = this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "hasBackCamera = " + hasBackCamera);
```

However, I tried to create an emulator without a front-facing or back-facing camera, and it still returns `true` for both checks. Is there some other way that I can detect the camera in Android?

Relevant documentation:

- [Take Photos > Request the camera feature](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskManifest)
- [PackageManager.hasSystemFeature()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#hasSystemFeature(java.lang.String))
- [PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY)
- [PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#FEATURE_CAMERA)

[image: AVD Manager, device with camera front and back set to "None"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After some research, it appears that this is a known bug, which has been unresolved for 10+ years now.**

See: [Emulator does not honour Camera support flag](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/36925409)

It seems that the only know work-around is to detect the number of cameras using the `Camera.getNumberOfCameras()` method, which has been deprecated since Android 5.0.

```java
boolean hasCamera = Camera.getNumberOfCameras() > 0;
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "hasCamera = " + hasCamera);
```

The above method seems to work on my emulator, despite the warning that it is deprecated.

---

Now according to the docs for [Camera.getNumberOfCameras()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera#getNumberOfCameras()):

"The return value of [getNumberOfCameras()] might change dynamically if the device supports external cameras and an external camera is connected or disconnected."

So perhaps `hasSystemFeature()` always returns `true`, because the device might later have an external camera attached?

Answer (score 0):

An emulator started by using a hardware configuration which enables or disables some features in runtime. It would be possible to add / change some configuration for your emulator.

I think, It is not removing camera hardware, just disables them. I created an emulator as you mentionned and there was no camera. When I changed the configuration I was able to use the camera. However, hasSystemFeature returned true for both situtation.

When you create an emulator, the settings you choose is written in hardware-qemu.ini for that AVD. You can find it in `~/.android/avd/YOUR_EMULATOR.avd/hardware-qemu.ini`. You can get exact path in `show on disk` on Device Manager.